# Pkcs7 signing in .Net with a certificate and a private key?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I have a working pkcs7 cryptography algorithm in Node.js

```
var forge = require('node-forge');
var fs = require('fs');
var privateKeyAssociatedWithCert = fs.readFileSync("certs\\confpack.key", 'binary');

const payload = fs.readFileSync("certs\\confpack.cert", 'binary');
const certOrCertPem = forge.pki.certificateFromPem(payload);

// create PKCS#7 signed data with authenticatedAttributes
// attributes include: PKCS#9 content-type, message-digest, and signing-time
var p7 = forge.pkcs7.createSignedData();
p7.content = forge.util.createBuffer('ABCD123');
p7.addCertificate(certOrCertPem);
p7.addSigner({
  key: privateKeyAssociatedWithCert,
  certificate: certOrCertPem,
  digestAlgorithm: forge.pki.oids.sha256,
  authenticatedAttributes: [
 ]
});

// PKCS#7 Sign in detached mode.
// Includes the signature and certificate without the signed data.
p7.sign({ detached: true });
console.log(forge.asn1.toDer(p7.toAsn1()).toHex());
```

My implementation using .Net and Org.BouncyCastle Nuget have a different result.

```
X509CertificateParser certParser = new X509CertificateParser();
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate rootCert = certParser.ReadCertificate(File.ReadAllBytes("cert\\confpack.cert"));

AsymmetricKeyParameter signatureKey;
using (var reader = File.OpenText("cert\\confpack.key"))
    signatureKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();

byte[] signedMessage = null;
CmsProcessable cmsData = new CmsProcessableByteArray(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCD123"));

var allCerts = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>();
allCerts.Add(rootCert);
var storeParams = new X509CollectionStoreParameters(allCerts);
var certStore = X509StoreFactory.Create("Certificate/Collection", storeParams);

CmsSignedDataGenerator cmsGenerator = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();
cmsGenerator.AddSigner(signatureKey, rootCert, NistObjectIdentifiers.IdSha256.Id);
cmsGenerator.AddCertificates(certStore);

CmsSignedData cms = cmsGenerator.Generate(cmsData, true);
signedMessage = cms.GetEncoded();

Debug.WriteLine(Hex.ToHexString(signedMessage));
```

NodeJs Result : "3082055406092a864886f70"...

.Net Result   : "308006092a864886f70"...

What am I missing in .net code? I really need to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The Node version generates a detached signature and .net an encapsulated one. For detache signature use:

cmsGenerator.Generate(cmsData, **false**)